# Delete all the content between <strong></strong> in Yahoo Pipes feed

Tags: regex, rss, yahoo-pipes

I'm pulling a feed from GMA, don't ask why.  I'm using yahoo pipes because I can filter out certain articles based on their title.  Then I run the feed through feedenlarger.com so I can get the full text pretty easily.

The problem I'm having is that the feeds contain bold links in them that are disrupting the articles.  Each one is surrounded by a `<strong>....</strong>`.  I am trying to just delete any content that exists between the `<strong></strong>`, but I can't seem to get it right.

I have tried:
item.description *replace* `&lt;strong&gt;*?&lt;/strong&gt;` *with* (and left blank)
as well as
item.description *replace* `<strong>*?</strong>` *with* (also left blank)

I know regex and html are not meant for one another, but if someone has a suggestion or direction, I'd appreciate it very much.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with what you are doing exactly, but I would first try just removing the `<strong>` tag to make the escape is needed. By that I mean see if `&lt;strong&gt;` or `<strong>` works to make sure you are on the right track.

I believe the source of the issue is that it appears you are trying to match many `>` rather than the actual contents between the tags. Try using `.*?` (or [^<]*? if you know there will be no other tags within the  tags) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help - turns out that I had to pull in the full feed to pipes in order for it to work.  Using the regex you mentioned did work though.  Much appreciated!